# How to implement columns check on this php server side check for textarea lines limit?

Tags: php, textarea

I've got my javascript client side code to check for that but just in case that it fails, i will need to add option to check not only lines but also columns per line for this php server side script. i will greatly appreciate any help on that and thanks for taking the time to check my question and possibly answer.

```
    $lines = array_slice(explode("\n", trim( $_POST['description'])), 0, 6); // max 6 lines

    foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
    {
        $lines[$key] = substr(trim($value), 0, 300); // max 300 chars
    }

    $insert['teams_descr'] = implode("\n", $lines);
        $this->db->update( 'teams', $insert, array( 'teams_id' => $this->user->leader_team_id() ) );
```

Comment: By "columns," do you mean the number of characters in a line?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant. Like this in html `<textarea cols="50"...` but I want to add this check server side in my php script since it only checks for lines at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $chars_per_line = str_split($value);
    if(count($chars_per_line) > 300){
      // Do something
    } else {
      // Do something  
   }
}
```

Comment: My current one above is actually doing the same thing as `substr()`. I've tested it but my current issue is that some characters such are as double bytes which produce errors, any way to prevent that ? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with multibyte characters, you need to use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) to get the length and [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to extract substrings:

```
$lines = array_slice(explode("\n", trim( $_POST['description'])), 0, 6); // max 6 lines

foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
    $lines[$key] = mb_substr($value, 0, 300);
}
```

If you're likely to be dealing with different text encodings, check the documentation for converting between encodings. If you have written the form that you're collecting data from, make sure that you set the text encoding and that your database uses the same encoding.

[Full list of multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

Comment: Why I can't just replace `substr` with `mb_substr` directly without checking the lenght as it is in my script ? And also can `mb_` functions work with one byte characters too?

Comment: Yes, you can go straight for the substr -- I've edited my answer accordingly. `mb_` functions work with both one and multi-byte characters.

Comment: So, its totally safe to use `mb_substr` instead of only `substr` to make sure only 300 valid characters will be applied right?`I mean it wont matter if they are single or double bytes ...

Comment: Yup. mb_substr knows which characters are two bytes and which are one, and will chomp the string accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and accept the answer as well. Much appreciated. I understood that its always better to use `mb_substr` in that case, so I wont worry about if someone use two byte characters ....

Comment: I tested it and it only worked correctly after setting the encoding to UTF-8 in the mb_substr function, that's correct right?

Comment: Yes, it should be set to the encoding that the input is in.